# From a Sequence to Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

Given a rational function, the coefficient of its Taylor series is a sequence. Often the sequence can be recursively defined. For a rational function $f(x)/g(x)$, we can consider its Taylor expansion at $x=0$, i.e.
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+\cdots
$$
**How can we go from the right to the left?**

That is, if we are given a sequence $(a_{n})$, and we know how $(a_{n})$ is recursively defined, then how can we find a rational function whose Taylor expansion is $(a_{n})$.

More specifically, the $(a_{n})$ that I really care about is defined as the following:
\begin{cases}
a_{0}=1,\; a_{1}=0,\; a_{2}=1 \\[2pt]
a_{n}=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}, & n \geq 3
\end{cases}

Comment: Sorry for the possible confusion. Actually, what I am looking for is that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials.

Comment: Are you certain that there **are** polynomials that make this work? If so, how do you know that?

Comment: "$a_n$ is recursively defined" does not guarantee you get a rational function, e.g., $a_0=1$, $a_{n+1}=2^{a_n}$ or $a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)$.  You need $a_n$ satisfies a constant-coefficient linear recurrence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Consider $G(x)=xF(x)+2x^2F(x)-x^3F(x)$ and assume $G(x)=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+...\;$ . Then for $n\geq 3$ we have $a_n=b_n$. Note that $b_0=0$, $b_1=a_0=1$ and $b_2=a_1+2a_0=2$, so
$$G(x)=x+2x^2+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\ldots=x+2x^2+(F(x)-1-x^2).$$
This means $xF(x)+2x^2F(x)-x^3F(x)=-1+x+x^2+F(x),$ and solving for $F(x)$ gives
$F(x)=\frac{-1+x+x^2}{-1+x+2x^2-x^3}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you distinguish $x$ and $X$?

Comment: No, I do not. I guess midway through the question I decided that capital $f$ deserves capital $x$.